Error connecting from VS Code to VM (OS Login, IAP)
I am trying to connect from VS Code on Windows to a Linux VM on Google Cloud.
I can ssh to the VM successfully from Google Cloud SDK Shell using gcloud compute ssh vm tunnel-through-iap. However, when I try using using gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel, the connection doesn't work. When I check sshd logs on the VM, I see:
error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 35.235.244.xx port xxxxx

The problem occurs also when I set up the VM as a host in the config file in VS Code and try to connect. If I use ProxyCommand cmd /c "gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel etc..."  I hit sshd on the VM, but it says:
error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 35.235.244.xx port xxxxx

Since the user can ssh successfully through the tunnel from the SDK shell, we can rule out permission and firewall issues. I gave the user Compute Admin permissions anyway just to rule out such problems while I troubleshoot this connection issue.
Any idea how I can get it to work? Thank you.

This error typically indicates an issue with the SSH handshake and also this could happen if the SSH server on the VM is blocked or misconfigured and also I would recommend you to reset the daemon with: service sshd restart and also try to restart the VS code and check if it is working.Also could you please confirm whether you have checked this link?

Thank you for your comment. If it was anything to do with sshd, I probably wouldn't be able to tunnel to the VM from my computer at all, but I can tunnel just fine outside VS Code. I can connect to it any (allowed) way I want with no problem. Rebooting the VM doesn't help. Regarding VS Code, I can use it to connect to VMs that don't use OS Login just fine. This is perhaps an important clue: when I run ProxyCommand gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel I cannot get it to even reach the VM unless I do ProxyCommand cmd /c "gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel", I feel it needs to be tweaked somehow.

And thank you for the link, I've looked at it and pretty every other link I could find on this problem, I've lost an entire day to troubleshooting this sadly.

I am glad the issue has been resolved and I will post this as a answer.What should I do when someone answers my question?

There may be a miscommunication here, the issue has not been resolved unfortunately.

Apologies for the miscommunication.The issue seems to be specific to how VS code interacts with ProxyCommand and also it could be due to how the gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel command is being invoked from within VS code.

I would kindly request you to go through this for the similar error message.Also please examine this and let us know whether it is helpful or not?

Did you have time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.

I just made some clarifications to the original post. The user can do ssh tunnel-through-iap in SDK Shell, but start-iap-tunnel doesn't work. sshd is managed by Google Cloud when using OS Login and it seems to work fine, so I cannot make changes to it. it clearly works fine for tunneling through IAP, it's start-iap-tunnel that's the problem. I am not sure why that fails. I looked at the links you provided but none of those things help. Forget about VS Code for a second - I need a way to make the start-iap-tunnel work in SDK Shell.

This error typically indicates an issue with the SSH handshake and also this could happen if the SSH server on the VM is blocked or misconfigured.
Additionally I would recommend you to reset the daemon with: service sshd restart and also try to restart the VS code and check if it is working.Please refer to  this for more information on this.

The issue has not been resolved. sshd works fine outside VS Code.
